# useEffect either doesn't give a result or goes into Infinite loop

Tags: reactjs

I really confused about useEffect. sometimes works and sometimes it does not.
for example this one,

```
    const [news, setNews] = useState<Array<MainNewsData>>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getNews();
    }, []);

    const getNews = () => {
        NewsService.getMainNews() // calling an api
      .then((response: any) => {
        setNews(response.data);
      })
      .catch((e: Error) => {
        console.log(e);
      });

    };
```

it gives me a `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency:  'getNews'. Either includes it or remove the dependency array`
if I add `news` will go into an infinite loop.
if I used useRef since I want just one render it works but if I tried to pass the result to another class, would give me an undefined.
What I really don't understand is this code works in a previous project but here not even after reading a lot of examples about how to fetch data using useEffect I still didn't figure out the solution.

one of the answers that I found is to add news.length as a dependency but it's not recommended.

another one is add a timer \:

What I should do?
any answer I will appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memoise `getNews` using `useCallback`:

```
const getNews = React.useCallback(() => {
  NewsService
  .getMainNews()
  .then((response: any) => setNews(response.data))
  .catch(console.log)
}, []);
```

Pass it to the `useEffect` dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getNews();
}, [getNews]);
```

This now works, because `getNews` is always the same function. In your original example, it was recreated after each render due to setting state. That caused the infinite loop.

This answer assumes `NewsService` is imported from a different file (or at least declared outside the render cycle), which it looks like it probably is.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's work and fetched correctly if you don't mind I have another question. now I try to filter my data depends on the categories, since the news is async when I try to use a filter, The result will be undefined. Like this {< FeatureNews currentFeaturesNews={news.filter((e) => e.category_title === 'Feature')} />}. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: What you have there shouldn't cause any issues if `news` starts as an empty array, and `response.data` is also an array of the expected format. If you mean that nothing shows when the component loads, that's expected and you might have to implement a loading element like a spinner. I can't go much deeper than that in comments, if you have another issue you should make a new question.